# Extracting specific information from a string list using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a string list with several thousands of URL values in different structures and I am trying to use regex to extract specific information from the URL values. The following gives you an example URL from which you can get an idea about the structure of this specific URL (note that there are many other records in this format, only the numbers changes across the data):

```
url_id | url_text
15     | /course/123908/discussion_topics/394785/entries/980389/read
```

Using the `re` library in python I can find which URLs have this structure:

```
re.findall(r"/course/\d{6}/discussion_topics/\d{6}/entries/\d{6}/read", text)
```

However, I also need to extract the '394785' and '980389' values and create a new matrix that may look like this:

```
url_id | topic_394785 | entry_980389 | {other items will be added as new column}
15     | 1            | 1            | 0       | 0     | 1    | it goes like this
```

Can someone help me in extracting this specific info? I know that 'split' method of 'str' could be an option. But, I wonder if there is a better solution.

Thanks!

Comment: If your string consists of a fixed number of fields, separated by `/`, then `split()` **is** the best solution.

Comment: Why not just use regex capturing groups?

Comment: Yes, you may use a regex with capturing groups with `re.finditer` so as to have access to the whole match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
import re

text = '/course/123908/discussion_topics/394785/entries/980389/read'
pattern = r"/course/\d{6}/discussion_topics/(?P<topic>\d{6})/entries/(?P<entry>\d{6})/read"

for match in re.finditer(pattern, text):
    topic, entry  = match.group('topic'), match.group('entry')
    print('Topic ID={}, entry ID={}'.format(topic, entry))
```

**Output**

```
Topic ID=394785, entry ID=980389
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I have another question. Is it possible to apply this to a `list`
 without using loops?

Comment: Something like `[text1, text2, text3,...]`

Comment: @renakre I'm not sure. What's wrong with iterating through a list?